# How to pass value of recursive function for tree

Tags: ocaml

I have recursive function, for course the  branch of the tree

```
type tree = Node of bool ref * (char * tree) list ref

type cours= tree ->char list -> char list* char list * tree

let cours t word=
 let rec cours_tree t word l1 l2=match t,word with
  | Noeud(r,n),[] -> Noud (r,n), l1 , l2
  | Noeud (r,n),x::h when (List.mem_assoc x !n) -> 
              x::l1,cours_tree (List.assoc x !n) h l1 l2
  | Noeud (r,{content=(c,b)::n),x::h  -> 
              x::l2,cours_tree (List.assoc x b) h l1 l2
 in
cours_tree t word [] []
```

I would expect this to Browse a tree from a given list of characters, and return the subtree reached, the character list and the list of those who could not be reached;
But I'm getting an error:

```
Error: This expression has type char list * 'a
       but an expression was expected of type 'a
       The type variable 'a occurs inside char list * 'a#
```

I dont know where is my problem.

Comment: Why did you cancel ivg's edit ? And what is this `Noud` ? If I change it to `Noeud` I don't have your error, I have a syntax error : `Syntax error: pattern expected` here : `Noeud (r,{content=(c,b)::n),`.
Please, edit your code so people can get the error you have if you want an answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are many problems:

1. `Noud` and `Noeud` are undefined constructors.
2. Unmatched `{` when you attempt to pattern match on the `ref`.
3. First `match` case returns `tree * list * list` but the other cases 
   return infinite types.
4. Incorrect `ref` pattern matching syntax. `content` should be `contents`.
5. Type error in the second `List.assoc`. `b` is a `tree` but an expression of type `(char * 'a) list` is expected.

The following code fixes the problems and while compile, but will not run correctly as the problem description you gave is not complete:

```
type tree = Node of bool ref * (char * tree) list ref

type cours = tree -> char list -> char list * char list * tree

let cours t word =
  let rec cours_tree t word l1 l2 =
    match t, word with
    | Node (r, n), [] -> Node (r, n), l1, l2
    | Node (r, n), x::h when List.mem_assoc x !n ->
        let t', l1', l2' = cours_tree (List.assoc x !n) h l1 l2 in
        t', x::l1', l2'
    | Node (r, {contents = (c, b)::n}), x::h ->
        let t', l1', l2' = cours_tree (List.assoc x n) h l1 l2 in
        t', l1', x::l2'
  in cours_tree t word [] []
```